# Team administrator vs. project administrator TFS

Tags: tfs

There doesn't seem to be too much documentation on team administrators, but if I went into my team's page and added a user as an administrator on the left-hand side, it's not making them project administrators, just something called a team administrator. What are the differences between the team administrator and project administrator with permissions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Project administrators can administer a project, team administrators are a new (2012+) role. A project can have multiple teams so their administration level is lower.

A project admin can therefore administer multiple teams.

A team administrator can administer the teams backlog, capacity, work items etc.

Answer (score 3):

Look for a first question on msdn page.

[How do permissions for Team Administrators compare with those set for Project Administrators?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409274.aspx)